# What parameters this formula takes when in "accumulate"?

Tags: c++, std, accumulate

This code is copied from another user question and I`m curious how accumulate works here.
I get the correct result from this code, but would like to know what parameters lcm takes when in "accumulate". The init as A and the sum of the range as b? Please help

```
#include <numeric>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (a == 0) return b;
        b %= a;
        if (b == 0) return a;
        a %= b;
    }
}

int lcm(int a, int b)
{
    int temp = gcd(a, b);

    return temp ? (a / temp * b) : 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 7, 9, 12 };

    int result = std::accumulate(arr, arr + 4, 1, lcm);

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: You could take a look at [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), or just add printf/cout statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument that `lcm` will take is the accumulated value so far (which starts at `1`, the third argument of `std::accumulate`), and the second argument will be an element in `arr`. Next, whatever `lcm` returns is passed as the first argument and the next element in `arr` as the second.

See [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for more details.

You could easily write `a` and `b` to the standard output inside `lcm` to see what's happening.

Comment: One more thing. 
    for (;;)
When should I use that kind of for loop? Is it until the function reaches return statement?

Comment: @Vallerious It's the same as `while (true)`, so it will just loop forever unless you break out of it using something like `break` or `return`.